# Embed one page in another one (Shortcodes?)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, wordpress-gutenberg

I designed a page with Gutenberg (+kadence blocks) and I would like to insert it into another page (product description of Woocommerce), where Gutenberg is not supported.
Is it possible to get the shortcode of the page I designed?

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to install Gutenberg with the shortcode there or use an iframe to display it the deisign.

Comment: I tried with an iframe but it included all the the website, not just the page. What do you mean with install gutenberg with shortcode?

Comment: I was thinking the other website is also WordPress and you can install Gutenberg there too. 

Yes for iframe to work you need to create new template where you output only the design you want in the other website.

Comment: it’s only one website, not two

Comment: My bad, so why you just don't use a filter and add 'do_shortcode()" inside? So you can display it in the product page